# CSS warnings-Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts

Tags: css

I try to validate my CSS code. I have no errors, only warning, but i dont like it.

I have 100 warnings, like this ones:

```
45 Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts #search and div.main_text
45 Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts div.testinput and div.main_text
45  Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts #submit and div.main_text
221 Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts div.test input and #index_be
221 Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts #login_submit and 


div.main_text {
  color: #a3986d;
}

#search {
    background-color:#a3986d;
}
```

What should I do with this?

Comment: How did you validate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore it. Provided you never have HTML like this:

```
<div id="search">
    <div class="main_text">
    Hello!
    </div>
</div>
```

you'll be fine. If you do have markup like that, then the contents of the `div` with class `main_text` will have a background colour of `#a3986d` and a foreground colour of `#a3986d`, so text won't show up.

The fact that there is such a combination isn't a problem, unless you use that combination.

Comment: I updated from background-color attribute to background

Answer (score 0):

for the Same action in CSS you can use following pattern. **Note That** with following code change all the mentioned class or ids so be carefull when you do this.

So To Apply one or multi attribute to a wide variety of classes or IDs seperate them with Comma like :

```
.MyFirstClass,   #YourFirstID,   div,   span
{
    /*any attribute you like to share with all of them*/
    color : black;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

So you have to remove all of 221 (or any other same numbers) attribute from all of 221 classes and just apply them in a series of classes. (it is better to do this in the top of your CSS class which whenever you change a sameproperty in the exact class, your change apply

Comment: i dont understand. i use color prop. for div_main_text, and background-color properties for search. If i dot what you mentioned, then both properties will applied to both. So the text will be unvisible?!